# problem with PHP on console / MAMP after updating MACOSX

Tags: php, macos, path, console, mamp

i've updated my MACOSX 10.6 and since then, i've not been able to use the PHP console version from MAMP.

php -v returns me 5.3.3 which is the PHP i've compiled and i want to use the one from MAMP

I've already done :

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin
```

and creating a .bash_profile and a .profile fileand i put in it : `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin`

without any results

`echo $PATH` returns :

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you reload the profile after altering .bash_profile?

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

(or .profile if you use that one)